# export (save) and import (source) shell variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I need to save environment variables to a file and (later) a process should import them. I need this to workaround a program `fooprog` that nullifies the environment before executing a `barscript`, and I need some environment variables in `barscript`. So I'm planning on saving all environment variables to a file before executing `fooprogram`, and make `barscript` source them from a file.

I tried this, but it doesn't work if there are variables that contain spaces.

```
$ env > my_environment
$ . my_environment
```

I guess the correct way is to fiddle with `/proc/$$/environ` and parsing this from `barscript` somehow, but I can't find the correct way of doing that.

edit: Quotes or newlines are problematic too. How could it be done so that envars as problematic as the following could be sourced without problems?

```
PROBLEMATIC='this has double quotes " and single quotes '\'' and even
newlines.

See?'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```sh
$ declare -p > my_environment
```

Later, inside `barscript`:

```
. my_environment
```

`declare -p` outputs environment variables in a form that can be executed by the shell, including quoting and escaping of variables as required.

```sh
$ foobar='"some double-quoted text"'
$ echo $foobar 
"some double-quoted text"
$ declare -p foobar
declare -- foobar="\"some double-quoted text\""
```

BTW, if you don't want to output your entire environment, you don't have to.  Just name the vars you want to output on the `declare -p` command line:

```
$ declare -p HOME PATH foobar
declare -x HOME="/home/cas"
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11"
declare -- foobar="\"double-quoted-text\""
```

or pipe through `grep -v` to exclude specific vars you don't want in the output.

To get only the exported variables:

```
declare -p -x > my_environment
```

For more info, see `help declare` in `bash`.

Comment: This is almost what I want. I've been looking at `help declare` and trying things, but I cannot find a way to only print the `export`ed envars.

Comment: the `grep -- -x` trick fails with multiline variables. I'm working on a way to get only the exported variable names to `declare -p $(...)` (cannot use `xargs` as `declare` is a builtin). I got `declare -p $(env -0 | grep -zo '^\w\+=' | sed -e 's/=$//')` which seems to work, although it seems little maintenance nightmare.

Comment: yep, see updated answer.  `declare -p -x`, no need for `grep`.

Comment: anyway @cas your help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: how the f*** did I miss `-x` in `help declare`????

Comment: I dunno.  "drugs" is the excuse I use :)